# java - выставление параметров для приложения через консоль

Tags: java, параметры

У меня возник вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы в команде `java` можно было выставлять параметры для проекта.

К примеру на C++ можно написать проект, который при запуске из консоли будет запрашивать параметры. Как сделать так же, но на java.

Еще пример, что в самой java машине можно указывать параметры по типу `-help`, `--add-modules`.

Comment: [Тыц](https://www.baeldung.com/java-console-input-output), и [тыц](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli)...

Comment: когда я написал `Console console = System.console(); String c = console.readLine("test: ");` у меня вылетела ошибка: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.Console.readLine(String, Object[])" because "console" is null
 at com.orl.orelconsole/com.orl.orelconsole.HelloApplication.main(HelloApplication.java:8)`

Comment: Импорт конечно-же у Вас есть... Или?! `import java.io.Console;` Со Scanner'ом не пробовали?

Comment: импорт я писал, а как со сканером `Console` использовать?

Comment: @adisteyf, так вы хотите обрабатывать параметры, которые передаются через командную строку (обрабатываются через параметр `String[] args` в методе `main`): `java -jar my.jar param1=value1`?  Можно передавать параметры как системные свойства `java -Dparam1=value1 -jar my.jar`.  Или же вы хотите считывать некие параметры из входного потока (консоли) `System.in`?

Comment: Я хочу считывать `System.in` в другом потоке, так чтобы при этом работал javafx одновременно

Comment: В первой [ссылке](https://www.baeldung.com/java-console-input-output#reading-from-systemin), которую я ранее Вам приводил, есть подробное описание использования.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно запустить JavaFX в другом потоке с помощью `Task` и в самом проекте сделать считывание с консоли через `nextLine` в `Scanner`.